# What should I use to draw a 3D trajectory line that I can rotate around - iOS

Tags: ios, core-animation, opengl-es-2.0

I am working on making an iOS game where a player can flick their finger to throw an object. After the object is thrown, I want to animate the trajectory of that object like in the linked image below. I also want to allow the player to rotate around the thrown object image in 3D. (think of someone throwing a baseball or a golfer hitting a ball and seeing the arc the ball makes in 3D)

My question is what would be the best way of accomplishing this?

I have looked into opengl-es 2.0, core animation, 3rd part frameworks like Cocos3D, etc. But I am not sure how low level I need to go to accomplish this.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

[trajectory Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLZYW.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use core animation. Core animation is 2.5D, not 3D. It allows you to animate flat image tiles in 3-D space. You'll need to use OpenGL or maybe SpriteKit or one of the other game APIs like Unity.

Regardless of which framework, you'll need to  understand 3-D transformation matrices and display frustums.

Stack overflow is not a good site for "which framework is the best" type questions, so I'm not going to  trying to answer that part of the question

Comment: Thank you for the great response! If you don't mind, would you happen to know if I would have to draw a shape as the trajectory (like a curved straw cylinder) or could I simply draw a line in 3D space in OpenGL? As you can probably tell, I am not totally familiar with OpenGL. I am just trying to get as much knowledge as possible, so that I can tailor my learning toward my end goal.

Comment: You probably want a parabolic curve. You'd need to come up with the formula for the parabola in 3-space, and then draw it as a series of line segments. You could certainly do that in OpenGL. It would be "straightforward", but that doesn't mean it would be easy. OpenGL has a helluva learning curve. More like a "learning cliff".

Comment: Makes sense. I have heard that OpenGL has a pretty steep learning curve...I will dive in and see what I can figure out. My impression is that the 3-space math will be the easiest part. As I dive into this, will report back if I have anything worth reporting. Thank you very much for your help!